# Monodevelop 4 Default Parameters c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm using Unity 4.3 with Monodevelop 4.0.1 and for some reason when I Build with Monodevelop (to check for errors) it complains about default parameters. Unity does allow default parameters. In Monodevelop 2 it was possible to change the version of c#, but I can't seem to find the same setting in Monodevelop 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have also ran into this problem. I have found a solution(it's terrible, be warned!)

1. Open Unity and load your solution in MonoDevelop 4.0.1 (older version you can set the target framework more easily)
2. Navigate to your project directory and open "Assembly-CSharp-vs" in notepad.
3. Change the line "TargetFrameworkVersion" v3.5 to "TargetFrameworkVersion" v4.0

You will have to do these steps every time you load Unity(blah) but it does work.

Comment: When I compile a  C# project using Monodevelop for Ubuntu Linux's Build General dropdown list setting of Mono-.NET 4.0, I get this gmcs compiler error: The type forwarder for type 'System.TimeZoneInfo' in assembly 'mscorlib' v2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral ,has circular dependency? Can I fix this error by either: 1. changing the Monodevelop 5.5 C# compiler running on Ubuntu Linux 15.10 to mcs.exe or  2)add the gmcs C# command line option,-sdk:4 through the Monodevelop 5.5 IDE running on Ubuntu Linux? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/176305/default-parameter-specifiers-are-not-permitted.html

- Follow the steps in the link
- Make sure you hit ok to save the settings.
- Reopen the window to double check that it has saved.
- I had to select each main "Assembly" folder and apply the change to each before it started working.

Comment: Yea I found that too, though those settings are from an older version of MonoDevelop, I can't find them in MonoDevelop 4.0.1.